# Formatting a FreeNAS ZFS volume as ext4 for Linux use?

Tags: truenas, zfsonlinux

I've setup a FreeNAS server with 6x 3TB drives for use as a backup NAS via iSCSI for a Linux server (Ubuntu 12.04). The FreeNAS setup was pretty straightforward and the logical step seemed to be to create a ZFS volume from the 3TB drives so I went down that path.

Ubuntu's iSCSI initiator page was pretty helpful (https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/iscsi-initiator.html) and it allowed me to configure the Ubuntu machine and have the 11TB FreeNAS drive appear as /dev/sdf

However I was unable to partition the drive. The Ubuntu disk utility would fail. So I just went ahead and did a `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdf` and it created an ext4 filesystem which I then was able to mount.

Have I done anything that will come back and bite me later by just using `/dev/sdf`?

Comment: Did you need to have partitions? What was the failure message from the "Ubuntu disk utility"?

Comment: No. I don't have a specific need for a partition. I've have to retry with the partitioning tool (after my current test copy completes) to determine the msg again - it was pretty obscure.